# Java: Corrupted ArrayList?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, arraylist

I have a REST project where I keep an `ArrayList` of users in an access control service class. Everything has been working fine, until suddenly the REST web service throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. Stepping through the codes, I realized that the `ArrayList` is weird:

1. Mousing over the field in Eclipse during step through causes `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.`. After some research, it seems that this happens when `toString()` is defined incorrectly. Well, I'm not sure what incorrectly here means.
2. The size of the `ArrayList` is `-1`.

The problem disappears after I restart the server, but I need to know what has caused this to happen. Anyone has any idea?

#### Edit

Someone requested for code, so I will paste parts that are related to the list.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccessControlServiceImpl implements AccessControlService {
    @Autowired
    private OnlineUserTracker userTracker;

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    public boolean checkAuthorized(String username) {
        User user = userDao.findById(username);

        // Other logic
        userTracker.getUsers().add(user); // If user is authorized
    }

    public void logoff(String username) {
        userTracker.removeUser(username);
    }
}

public class OnlineUserTracker {
    private List<User> users;

    public OnlineUserTracker() {
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    
    public User getUserFromUsername(String username) {
        for (User user : users) {
            if(user.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void removeUser(String username) {
        User user = getUserFromUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            users.remove(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you allowing multiple threads to interact with the ArrayList without correct synchronization?

Comment: @jtahlborn Hmm, I didn't write this (my colleague did it), but as far as I can see, multiple threads can interact with the `ArrayList` and there is no obvious synchronization done.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, synchronization problem could have caused symptom 2, but symptom 1 is just too strange.

Comment: can u confirm if arraylist is from the class java.util. package or some other ?

Comment: I believe any exception thrown as eclipse tries to get the string to display will be caught and rethrown as an InvocationException. So just about anything could be going wrong. But given the list is in a corrupt state at that point (as evidenced by the size) it's not surprising that your debugger can't display its value.

Comment: @Enzokie These are the codes interacting with the list.

Comment: @user641887 It definitely is from `java.util`, and also not extended in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the issue is incorrect concurrency, a good solution is to wrap all interaction with the list inside OnlineUserTracker and then synchronize the relevant methods (that means no methods should return the underlying List).  In fact, regardless of how you solve the problem, it would be a better design to not ever expose the List to code outside of OnlineUserTracker (i.e. encapsulation).

A "simple" solution would be to make the List an instance of CopyOnWriteArrayList.  This implementation is thread-safe for normal interactions as well as iteration.  However, if you are frequently adding or removing users, it may be less efficient.

Comment: So in your opinion, there is a very good chance that the problem occurred due to concurrency and synchronization issues?

Comment: @Jai - if you have multiple threads using a common ArrayList using the code you showed, then you _have_ a concurrency problem regardless of whether or not it is the cause of this issue.  Also, getting a common utility (e.g. ArrayList) into an "impossible" state (e.g. size -1) is generally a pretty good sign that you have a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

So from my point of many things could go wrong.

But if You got ArrayList and You say its size is -1 . that is wierd. 
list.size() should never return negative value.

On the other hand something like this could happen if You try to get index of object on the list and this object is not present in such list...

So possibly that was the case. and reason for that could be accessing that list from other thread and removing it before indexOf() method call. or maybe sending 2 requests to your server. second request clearly would produce such problem :)